# How do I use React Native onLongPress properly?

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, touchablehighlight, touchablewithoutfeedback

I have a simple piece of code that's just a TouchableOpacity with a onLongPress prop, but it does not seem to be working.

```
<TouchableOpacity delayLongPress={10} onLongPress={()=>{console.log("pressed")}} activeOpacity={0.6}>
  <Text>BUTTON</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I've tried removing the delay prop but that still doesn't work. Changing onLongPress to onPress does seem to work however, but I want the long press functionality. I'm testing this on an Android simulator.

Answer (score 11):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4944) this happens randomly, after testing on a real device with React Native Debugger enabled. Disabling React Native Debugger will make your problem go away.

Comment: `delayLongPress={10}` delays the function call for 10 milliseconds, that's why it looks like it's instant. Try setting it to a value > 1000 for example.

Comment: That doesn't matter, onLongPress is not being called.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to show a view on long press and hide it on release :

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={this._onPress}
    onLongPress={this._onLongPress}
    onPressOut={this._onPressOut}
>
            ....
</TouchableOpacity>



_onLongPress = () => {
    this.setState({
        modalVisible: true
    })
}
_onPressOut = () => {
    this.setState({
        modalVisible: false
    })
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can test on a IOS simulator or in the release package.